# Special character in localization key

Tags: ios, swift, localization, formatting

I've recently come across a crash in my app caused by what I think is an issue of formatting in my localization keys.

While special characters in the value of a key is quite flexible, I'm trying to make some keys containing a `.` as follows :

`"x_articles.one" = "%s product"`

The `.` inside the key seems to make my app crash.

I've been looking for some posts or documentation on this specific topic but couldn't find any.

So here are my questions :

- Are you aware of any formatting restrictions for localization **keys** ?
- Is there any documentation on this topic, or something that would come close that you could refer me to ?

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: Are you sure it's about the `.` and not the placeholder `%s`? I would have expect `%@`, or `%d`, but not `%s`. How do you use that translation exactly? What's the code? If you remove the `.`, it doesn't crash?

Comment: At first glance: no, the `.` is not causing the crash.  You should dig into the crash log specifics, and post them here! =)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I ended up figuring out why it was crashing, and it has nothing to do about my initial question.

The imports of the localizable files got wrong and sent me the android version of them, having `%s` instead of `%@` as @Larme mentioned it.

Getting the iOS import actually fixed it.